# Input field add symbols

Tags: javascript, php

This a function that allows people to type only English characters and numbers in a text field. Basically I need to update this function and allow to type in symbols too. I don't know anything about javascript function and I would appreciate if someone could send me the updated function. I know it might be really easy to do it if I knew how to code

Is there anyone who can help? Thank you

```
function add_js_code() {
  echo "<script>jQuery('.wc-pao-addon-wrap input[type=\"text\"], .wc-pao-addon-wrap textarea').keyup(function(){
 var input_val = jQuery(this).val();
 var inputRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
        var inputResult = inputRGEX.test(input_val);
          if(!(inputResult))
          {     
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');
          }
});</script>";
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_code' );
```

Comment: Why you want to use JS when you are not applying any filter on input text? You need just `<input>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Replace your regex 
FROM

```
var inputRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
```

TO

```
var inputRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]/;
```

You can also modify the